# Django Локальный шрифт

Tags: python, django

Не получается подключить шрифты, хранящиеся в папке static/fonts. Сам путь django насколько я понимаю видит, но шрифт не загружается на сайт

static/css/main.css:

```
.container {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: url("../fonts/font-light.ttf");
}
```

Comment: У вас настроена выдача static-файлов?

Answer (score 0):

В самый верх файла `main.css` попробуйте вписать:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('../fonts/font-light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal; /* жирность и другие параметры сами можете выставить */
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Потом этот MyFont можно будет использовать во всей вёрстке.